# “Distinguished element” in group theory

Tags: group-theory

I have asked that given a short list of triples of a set, a binary operation on the set, and a distinguished element, whether they forms a group. For example, the set is Z, the operation is addition and distinguished element is 1. In this context, what does **distinguished element** mean ?

I know that the integer set with addition is a group with identity element 0, but if distinguished element means identity element, they don’t form a group.

Comment: Is there a direct quote of the problem that you can give?

Comment: "Identity" means **with respect to the binary operation in question**.  Since the operation is +, we want the **additive identity**, i.e., $0$.  Meanwhile, $1$ is the **multiplicative identity**.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this question has received 3 answers (so far). This question is unclear --- it's not certain if the OP is confused with a definition or has been given an incomplete definition. The first comment goes after this in a circumspect way. The somewhat effuse answers reflect the uncertainty in the question. I have downvoted this question because I find it unclear.

Comment: My view is that the Question reflects the OP's confusion (about the meaning of "distinguished element") with sufficient effort and clarity to be worth answering.  Whether it deserves a permanent place on the site is a different matter.  Years ago there was a close reason for Questions that reflected a problem that would be unlikely to be of wider interest, but we no longer have that.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen these exercises before.  This is what your book is asking you:  given a trio of data as:

- a set $G$
- an operation $\ast$ on $G$
- an element $x_0 \in G$ (your "distinguished element")

does $\ast$ give a group operation on $G$ with identity $x_0$?  Thus, for example, the answer for the data $(\mathbb{Z}, + , 1)$ is "no" but for the data $(\mathbb{Z}, + , 0)$ is "yes."

Answer (score 1):

The distinguished element,  call it $e$, needs to satisfy $e*g=g*e=g\,,\forall g\in G$.

Since, in your example,  $1+g\neq g\,,\forall g\in\Bbb Z$, we don't have a group.

The gist of it is that if we change the distinguished element,  but keep the operation as addition, we no longer have a group.

Comment: As I wrote in one of my comments, $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 0)$ is a group, while $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 1)$ is not.  Which is what Christ Custer wrote as well.  And what do you mean by "having" to downvote?  Is that part of your official duties?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Some definitions have a distinguished elements which is the identity as part of the definition of group, typically in more categorical approaches (as it is useful for defining group object).

Comment: @MorganRodgers Look up group object on wikipedia or nlab. Using this approach, somewhat ridiculously, groups are the group objects in the category of sets, although you can insist on a definition forcing groups to be "pointed"(having distinguished elements) without going that far. I am sure there are books that have in the definition that groups have distinguished elements(maybe Algebra Chapter 0, I don't remember). I think it is clear from the context of the question that is the definition is a pointed version of groups. So $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is not a group but $(\mathbb Z, +,0)$ is a group.

Comment: As an analogy you can think of fundamental groups, where you need to define a basepoint to define the trivial element but in practice(after a first class) people don't really bother.

Comment: @MorganRodgers If they where using "your" definition why would they mention distinguished elements in the question? They mention in the first sentence that they are given an operation, a set, and a distinguished element and whether that forms a group, is the distinguished element a red herring/not relevant?

Answer (score -1):

A relic of abstractionist parlance.  "Distinguished" just means "specific".  So, what they mean is that, in a group, the identity element is a *specific* element (with the required properties).

Therefore, the answer to your question is: the triple $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 0)$ is a group, while the triple $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 1)$ is not.

---

Some more background to guard against future difficulties arising from the abstractionist approach--which some will find tangent and ranty--**but, in the end, I will re-address your question in terms of what follows**.

This misunderstanding (and many others) would not even arise if groups were introduced properly; i.e., as groups of transformations.

**Definition:**  A *transformation* of a set $X$ is a 1-to-1 correspondence from $X$ to $X$.

**Corollary:**  Composition of transformations of $X$ gives transformations of $X$, and this composition is associative.

This Corollary can be proved by direct inspection of composition.

**Definition:** A nonempty collection of transformations of $X$ is called *a group of transformations of $X$* if this collection contains all compositions and inverses of its members.

**Examples:** i) $X$ = the Cartesian $xy$-coordinate plane, the transformations are the rotations of $X$ about the origin. ii) $X$ is a finite set, and the transformations are all permutations of $X$. iii) $X$ is any set, and the collection of transformations contains just one transformation: the one that maps every $x$ in $X$ to itself.  This transformation is called *the identity transformation of $X$* will be denoted by $1_{X}$.

There is only one identity transformation: if there were two, multiply them, and the product equals each of them, hence they are the same.

**Theorem:**  If $G$ is a group of transformations of a set $X$, then $G$ contains the identity transformation $1_{X}$.

**Proof:**  If $g$ is a transformation in $G$, then so is $g^{-1}$ (by the latter definition), and therefore so is $g \circ g^{-1} = 1_{X}$.  Done.

If now we define an *abstract group* (the uninformative formalist way it's usually done: a set, a binary operation, a "distinguished" identity element, etc.), then:

**Every abstract group is isomorphic to a group of transformations of some set.**

(Why?  If $G_{abs}$ is an abstract group, then each $g \in G_{abs}$ gives us the transformation $x \mapsto gx$ of the set of the elements of $G_{abs}$.)

Therefore, **groups of transformations really give us ALL the groups that exist.**

For finite groups, the version of this last boldfaced statement is [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).

---

To address your question in terms of groups of transformations:

Consider the shift of all integers by some constant integer (positive, negative, or zero). Such shifts are transformations of the set $\mathbb{Z}$. Among these, the identity transformation is the one that leaves all the integers in place; i.e., the shift by 0.  The shift by 1 is **not** the identity transformation.

That's why $(\mathbb{Z},+, 0)$ is a group, and $(\mathbb{Z},+,1)$ is not.

Comment: So, umm, does NMZ's example form a group?

Comment: Yes for $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 0)$, and no for $(\mathbb{Z}, +, 1)$.

**Reason:** consider the shift of all integers by some constant integer (positive, negative, or zero).  Such shifts are transformations of the set $\mathbb{Z}$.  Among these, the identity transformation is the one that leaves all the integers in place; i.e., the shift by $0$.

See also my comment under the OP.

Comment: You are evading the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What issue still needs to be addressed?

Comment: Whether NMZ's example forms a group. Your answer is "yes and no".

Comment: Yes if the "distinguished element" is $0$, and No if it is $1$.  Is that distinction not apparent in the triples I wrote?

Comment: OK, so your answer is "no".

Comment: Do you want to let the OP decide that?

Comment: This seems sort of ranty in a way that doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Randall, edited.